# Preserving space within elements and removing blank space (empty rows) between elements XSLT, CSS

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

Been trying to transform an xml document, using output html method, for display in browser using xsl stylesheet (with CSS). Would like to display the following code

```
 <paragraph> 
 <content>Source                   A</content>
 </paragraph>
 <paragraph>
 <content>Color                       Yellow   </content>
 </paragraph>
```

as

```
Source                   A
```

```
Color                       Yellow
```

with space preserved between "Source" and "A", and space preserved between "Color" and "Yellow", but space (blank rows) removed between the rows. I am able to do either, for example wrapping the content nodes with pre nodes preserves space within the elements, and using

```
  <p>
  { margin:0}
```

removes the blank space between the rows. However I haven't been able to accomplish both concomitantly. Played with various options such as whitespace:pre, xsl:preserve-space, and many other combinations without success.
Thanks

Comment: The generic answer is below, for a more specialized one we'd need to see your XSLT code.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT preserves whitespace. HTML just by default does not show it.

Use this CSS directive:

```
p { 
  white-space: pre;
}
```

and XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="content" /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It seems to wrap all the rows into one block, but we would like to keep the rows distinct, only no blank space (rows) in between. It also doesn't preserve space within an element. One thing I didn't mention is that the stylesheet and xml document are constrained by the CDA specifications, so this may factor here. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what "CDA specifications" are. ;) But I know that XSLT does not touch whitespace in the source document *unless* you explicitly instruct it to. Also, as I said above, for a more specific answer you need to share your XSLT code.

Comment: The stylesheet is available here: https://www.lantanagroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/cda.xsl_.zip Thanks

Comment: Stripped down to the bare minimum but otherwise unchanged your XSLT works perfectly with my suggestion: http://www.xmlplayground.com/qUz3u8. So unless we are not talking about the same thing...

Comment: Thanks for providing a working test interface. I works nicely, still not for unstripped stylesheet and not sure whether it can also accomplish the "margin:0" thing, but helpful.

Comment: Look at the HTML source code your XSLT produces. Is the whitespace there? If yes, then your problem has nothing at all to do with XSLT, but with CSS.